# Adapter for Parktool SWB15

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools

I recently purchased a break bar:

https://www.parktool.com/product/3-8-drive-breaker-bar-swb-15

[image]

But have now come to realise that that I need an adapter between it and my bottom bracket key.

[image]

Any ideas on what these adapters are called? and/or where to find them?

Comment: Any decent hardware store would have the adapter.

Comment: A breaker bar is a nice tool to have, but for this application a 12" adjustable spanner is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Oh so apparently they're called socket adapters

[image]

Comment: They are most commonly 1/4" male to 3/8" female, 3/8'  male to 1/2" female and 1/2" male to 3/4" female. They do however make adapters that go from smaller driver to larger socket  such as 3/8" male to 1/4" female etc. for use where clearance is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

A 1” socket or whatever fits on the external hex is another option. Personally, I’d be tempted to go this route if only because I’m not so sure how strong those adaptors are under breaker bar levels of torque.

Comment: The downside of stacking things like this is that the torque is not applied at a good angle and tends to induce a twist.

Comment: I would be surprised if the adaptors didn't survive typical torques used in car or tractor repair. MUCH more than we use on bikes.

Comment: Fair points everyone.